# Efficient way to compare result and send a custom object in scala

Tags: scala

```
val date2 = Option(LocalDate.parse("2017-02-01"))
case class dummy(val prop:Seq[Test])
case class Test(val s :String,val dt:String)
case class Result(val s :String)

def myFunc:Result = {
  val s = "11,22,33"
  val t = Test(s,"2017-02-06")
  val list = dummy(Seq(t))
  val code = Option("22")
  val result = code.exists(p => {
    list.prop.exists(d => d.s.split(",").contains(p) && (LocalDate.parse(d.dt).compareTo(date2.get)>=0))
  })

  if (result) {
    Result("found")
  } else {
    Result("Not Found")
  }
}
```

The code determines the result based on condition.
Is there a efficient way to achieve the above in scala using map and avoiding `date2.get`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check pattern matching, as far as i can see, you have several cases:
- Code
- list
- date2

One way to avoid date2.get is this one belows:

```
   (code, list, date2) match {
      case (Some(p), dummy(l), Some(d2)) if l.exists(d => d.s.split(",").contains(p) && (LocalDate.parse(d.dt).compareTo(d2) >= 0)) => Result("found")
      case (_, _, _) => Result("Not Found")
    }
```

Also i don't know why you want to use map. It seems to me that this is not the proper tool for this job

Comment: please check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955499/combine-condition-inside-flat-map-and-return-result